# Barcode manufacturers

Tags: barcode

I'm hoping that someone here has worked with UPC/Coupon barcodes before.  Part of every UPC/Coupon barcode is a manufacturer code.  I need to database every manufacturer code.  Does anyone have any idea where to find a database of these manufacturer codes?

Comment: This seems like the wrong place for this question, though I'm not sure of the right one...

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search for "upc database" turned up several different ones.  Sadly, you are probably not going to find a definitive database.  Some stores use their own UPCs internally, and then you also have the abbreviated UPCs as well (look at a can of Pepsi to see what I mean).

Answer (score 1):

See https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/562/does-there-exist-a-global-database-of-all-products-with-ean-13-barcodes which has a very similar question. Among the options listed in that thread [The Product Open Data](http://www.product-open-data.com) project looks to be the most promising. There you can download their entire catalogue database, and that database has a column of all the Global Company Prefixes (GCPs) they have captured.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few resources I found:

http://www.upcdatabase.com/

http://www.ean-search.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the U.S. (I am assuming), you can use [this site to search by GTIN](http://gepir.prod.gs1us.org/GEPIR/jsp/client.jsp), which (in the U.S.) is the same as a 12-digit UPC code (from a barcode scan) with the digits "00" prefixing the UPC, making it a total of 14 digits and GTIN-14 compliant.  To see an example, use "00028000133177" for a test search.

That search will give you the GLN for the manufacturer.

I've found the [wikipedia's explaination of UPCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code) to also be very helpful.